# Mouse issues and Ctrl + Tab action happening randomly on 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, touchpad

I have recently install Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire (E5-574-58H3). For the most part everything is working perfectly however, after a period of a few hours use, it becomes very difficult to move my mouse pointer - it no longer responds normally. Not only is it difficult to move but it also seems to want to scroll the page up/down etc - almost as if it is detecting two fingers rather than one.

Also around this time, the Ctrl + tab functionality starts running completely at random - switching between programs without being asked to. I know it's a long shot, but does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this because at the moment I need to save my work and restart to resolve it.

P.s Sorry for the potentially confusing post; it's a rather difficult bug to describe!

Comment: My usual fix for anything like this (on any operating system) is to assume a key has got stuck (virtually, not physically) down, so press all alt, control, shift etc keys, and escape a few times and then try again.

Comment: Hi @DrEval  - I had considered that but the reason why I don't believe that this is the issue is because: a) it happens completely at random (even if the buttons have not been pressed for some time), b) it's a completely new laptop, c) it's unlikely that two buttons would get stuck at exactly the same time, d) it happens at around the same time as my mouse issues and e) I also have windows installed and neither issue happens on there.  All these reasons make me believe that they are software issues rather than a hardware issues.

Comment: Does it seem like your fans are running a lot?  Does it feel like it is getting too hot when this happens?  These are only thoughts that came to mind.

Comment: Hi @Terrance - no it doesn't seem like it is getting too hot and my fans don't appear to be running more than usual. The rest of the operating system seems to be completely fine, I can still work and use my computer relatively normally while this is happening - it's just more difficult without the mouse and with the random window switching haha.

Comment: @Terrance Thank you for your time :) When it next happens I'll have a look at the system load and see if there is anything obviously wrong. Will also see if I can dig out more information from the log files.